# LINQ filter string with value string

Tags: c#, linq, filter

I have a `string str = "abc,def,ghi"`. The length of string will vary. There could be one or more values separated by comma.

I have an object that has a property Code that is string and can contain values such as - `"abc, stu, xyz"`

I'm trying to filter objects from a collection that will return only those that contain a string in `str`

So, if `object.Code = "abc, stu, xyz"`  and `string str = "abc,def,ghi"` then return the object.

```
objects.Where( x => x.Code.Split(',').Any(s => (???)) );
```

where ??? is where my string `str` values will come in.

Thanks,

Comment: Lync != LINQ.  I'm updating the tags.

Comment: thanks, guess using too many MS products :-)

Comment: So if I'm understanding this....  Code is a property on a class, and if any of the comma separated strings in str are contained in the comma separated list of Code, then you want to return the "Code" object?

Comment: Is it possible for the value of `Code` to contain spaces as shown in your post?

Comment: Code is a property of class yes and it contains comma separated values - No spaces in either strings. My mistake on that.

Comment: I want to return the Whole object not just code. If "any substring" in Code property matches "any substring" of string str then RETURN object. Did the code snippet show Code being returned? That wouldn't be correct then. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = objects.Where(x => x.Code.Split(',').Any(s => (str.Split(',').Any(f => f.Equals(s)))));
```

Comment: in case there are spaces in either string, can we not do the following?
var result = objects.Where(x => x.Code.Split(',').Any(s => (str.Split(',').Any(f => f.Trim()Equals(s.Trim())))));

Comment: will be creating a short project to test out the code and let you know.
thanks

Comment: That would work. By the way, be aware of string comparison is culture-sensitive. https://benscabbia.co.uk/programming/ordinal-vs-culture-comparison-in-csharp

Answer (score 1):

Conversion of the `str` to a `HashSet` will improve the testing speed and simplify the query, but perhaps is overkill if your `objects` only have a few entries. I assume the `Code` property does not have spaces after each comma.

```
var strHash = str.Split(',').ToHashSet();
var ans = objects.Where(o => o.Code.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Any(c1 => strHash.Contains(c1)));
```